How to fix custom PDF in which text doesn't show up?
Context of the issue.
I host two DnD games and I am a player in one. Due to recent WoTC nonsense, I have been looking for alternatives. I dug up an old Google doc I used to use back when I previously GMed for this kind of game. So with a new group of potential players I decided to spend some time to transfer these PDFs to Tabletop Simulator using the custom PDF tool.
I managed to get the Age of Rebellion core rulebook, the Edge of the Empire core rulebook, all of the EotE career sourcebooks, all AoR career sourcebooks, all 3 era sourcebooks, all 3 essential collection books, Lords of Nal Hutta, Suns of Fortune, Strongholds of Resistance, and all Force and Destiny career sourcebooks.
Here's the issue.
The Force and Destiny core rulebook and F&D Nexus of the Power sourcebook are all blank, but in my browser their PDFs are just fine and read as normal.
For reference, here is a screenshot of p.60 of the Force & Destiny core rulebook and the Nexus of Power book (I do not recall the page number. Screenshot was taken yesterday.)









This is what it looks like in my browser (albeit at a lower quality because I had to zoom out to capture the full page).
This is the same page in Tabletop Simulator.



I have tried reuploading; I have tried deleting it from my Steam cloud and documents folders; I tried redownloading it - nothing seems to work for these two books. Nothing that I have tried, that is.
What I need to know.
How do I fix this? How do I make these two books usable in Tabletop Simulator?

Cached files is likely why it shows normally locally but is broken remotely. You and/or the others could try to clear the cache by disabling mod caching, reloading the mod, and then enabling mod caching again. If that fails it may be somehow corrupted, but you could try using a workaround (open in Acrobat > print > save as PDF).

"All blank" means you can leave through them, they give the right amount of pages, but are simply completely white? Are the PDFs editable, by chance?

@Joachim It is a custom pdf using the in game custom pdf tool. It is not fillable. I provided a screenshot of what it should look like. I also provided a link to a screenshot on steam that shows what it looks like in game.

When you upload the pdf to TTS, are you providing the custom pdf tool a link to your online copy of the pdf, or the local file path to where it's stored on your computer?

Basically my process was downloading the pdf's online and storing them in a folder on my computer. Then I would launch TTS, click the "Cloud Manager" option, clicked the folder icon next to the search bar, opened the file with PDFs, clicked the desired PDF, upload. Next I would open up the objects menu, custom objects, custom PDFs, open the PDF file, select the desired PDF, use the cloud option when uploading, then clicked import. Wait a few minutes and then it would be in game.

Two potential solutions are given here in the Steam Community forums [edited]:

For the rulebook, I used Acrobat's Export Pages option first to make mini-books, since the rulebook is too big for a single custom pdf. I made copies of the rulebook's separated sections, e.g. classes, races, equipment, talents, magic, magic items, etc. Each into its own pdf. Then I saved as JPEG for each one, and re-imported the pages into blank PDFs as images, then imported into Tabletop Simulator as "Custom PDF", with very nice results.


I found that, at least with D&D Beyond character sheet PDFs, if you print the pdf from Acrobat, then for 'printer' choose "PDF" and save it as a new file, it will open in Tabletop Simulator properly, with all of the text.

A reconversion of the PDF file sounds like a good starting point, anyway. I can't imagine the game can't render text in unknown fonts, but maybe the text is improperly marked in the file header, and not recognized as consisting of regular language characters by Tabletop Simulator.
Therefore, what might work is converting the text to outlines ("Create Outlines" or "Convert to Shape Object").
These are vector paths, retaining the look and crispness of the text, but not their symbolic function (e.g. search won't work anymore).
Another but cruder solution is to convert the text/pages to images, and then stitch them together as a new PDF. You will lose zoomability, crispness, and symbolic function, but then at least it should work.

The print to pdf would have been my suggestion as well. With a reasonably clever pdf reader you can even keep the text as text but still throw away some higher level features of the document that I would suspect to be the reason for the problem.
